# Left sourdough starter out overnight after feeding and it overflowed?

Tags: sourdough-starter

I have a new sourdough starter I made about 2 weeks ago. I took it out of the fridge yesterday afternoon and fed it.  It was slow to rise and even placed in the oven with light for a about an hour.  I checked in the evening and nothing, then forgot about it and went to bed.  Next morning it has overflowed.  Is it still good, what should I do with it after sitting out for 18 hours?  Can I put it in the fridge again and use it in a couple days?  Do I need to feed it again before using it to make bread?

Deanna

Comment: Welcome to the site.  It's fine.  You can use a larger container. I would encourage you to search the site to see if you find the answer to your questions before posting a new question.  Take a look at the related questions linked to this question, for example...or use the search bar.

Answer (score 1):

Since yeast will survive up to 55C, unless your oven with the light on is unusually hot, your starter still has active yeast. It overflowed because (at least for some period of time) there were the ideal conditions for rapid growth of the yeast. Certainly you should feed it now, just as you would every 24 hours.